# Working with Stripes, Javascript and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, stripes

This is my jsp page (which is a modal page to another jsp page ) which contains a table, a form, a javascript and ajax .

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/includes/taglibs.jsp" %>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve">

function invoke(form, event, container) {        
        var params = Form.serialize(form, {submit:event});
        new Ajax.Updater(container, form.action, {method:'post', parameters:params});
    }
</script>

<display:table name="actionBean.currentAidApplicantYear.comments" id="result" class="maui">
    <display:column property="lastUpdatedBy" title="Last Updated By" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="lastUpdatedTimestamp" title="Last Updated Date"
                    format="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="comment" title="Memo"/>
</display:table>
<div class="actionBar" style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: center;">
    <stripes:form beanclass="${actionBean.class}" id="addMemoForm" method="POST">
                <tags:labelAndValue label="Comment" name="comment" >
                    <stripes:textarea id="commentTextArea" name="comment.comment" cols="75"/>
                </tags:labelAndValue>
        <stripes:submit name="saveCommentAjax" value="Add Memo"
                        onclick="invoke(this.form, this.name, 'result');"/>
        <stripes:hidden name="id" />        
    </stripes:form>  
</div>
```

And this is part of the action bean which extends another class which in turn implements ActionBean, ValidationErrorHandler

```
Public class  CommentsTab extends AbstractAidApplicantTab {
private AidApplicantYearComment comment;

    public AidApplicantYearComment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }
    public void setComment(AidApplicantYearComment comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }
public Resolution saveCommentAjax(){
                    String result = String.valueOf(comment.getComment());
                    comment.save();//build up the comment object 
//by this time the comment object will save the string comment, user who updates it and a //time stamp. Those are the three variables that are displayed on the jsp table.
        return new StreamingResolution("text/html",new StringReader(result));}
//here instead of returning just a string “result” I prefer to return a comment object or //the three values I wanted to display on a table. How can I do that?
```

When the submit button is clicked I use an ajax to call an action bean’s method to do some operation and the function returns a streaming resolution **(StreamingResolution("text/html",new StringReader(result));)**.  Once I get the response I wanted to refresh the table without refreshing the page. However, in order to do that I have to get an object (**a comment object)** from the response not a text (or may be an array of Strings which might contain the values of the object)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`JavaScriptResolution`](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/ajax/JavaScriptResolution.html), or (better IMHO),

- transform your Comment object into a JSON String (using one of the myriads of free Java JSON encoders available),
- return that JSON String as a StreamingResolution
- use the native JSON functions in the browser (if you target recent browsers) or a JS library containing a JSON parsing function to transform the JSON string into a JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have never worked with JSON before. Any ways I will try it.

Comment: Which one do you think is easier using JavaScriptResolution or JSON?

Comment: They're both easy. JSON is standard, and doesn't need to use eval().

Comment: I started using JSON and it was throwing "There is a cycle in the hierarchy" ... and to fix that i found out other articles that mention about using JSONConfig ... here is one of the links http://albert-myptc.blogspot.com/2011/09/netsfjsonjsonexception-there-is-cycle.html ... but i couldnt understand what he is trying to do with his solution .. specially the config.setExcludes part was confusing ... I thought the guy is using a database table column name and i did the same thing and then i got another error which says java.sql.SQLExcpetion Unsupported feature. Any clue how i can fix it? Thanks

Comment: You have just three fields you must send. I would simply use a dedicated simple object with three properties and serialize this object to JSON, or use a library that allows creating a JSON object explicitely and doesn't serialize Java objects.

Comment: This what I did.
JsonConfig config=new JsonConfig();            config.setExcludes(new String[]{"LAST_UPD_BY","LAST_UPD_TS","COMMENT_TXT"});        config.setIgnoreDefaultExcludes(false);            config.setCycleDetectionStrategy(CycleDetectionStrategy.LENIENT);
            JSONObject JSONComment = JSONObject.fromObject(comment,config);
            
            JSONComment.put("comment", getComment());
            return new StreamingResolution("application/json", JSONComment.toString());
is that what you mean? sorry its just my first time working JSON and I might not be catching up easily.

Comment: I don't even know which JSON API you're using. No, what I mean is to create a simple JsonComment class containing your three fields only, and serialize this object. Or use an API which allows creating a JSONObject directly: JSONObject o = new JSONObject(); o.setField("text", myComment.getText()); ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7865/discussion-between-matx-and-jb-nizet)